# Can't figure out how to query only for last 30 days result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have this code to count visitors number from distinct ip adrress for all days stored in  the table.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("visitorsCount");
$page = $_GET['page']; //Page users visited with their ip
$queryTest = 'SELECT date, count(*),count(distinct ip) FROM `visitors`  where section=\''.$page.'\' group by date order by date';

$result= mysql_query($queryTest);

    $data = array();
    while($ris=mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {           
           $data[$ris[0]]=$ris[1];      // Render Visitor Count
        } 

    print_r($data);
```

So, Print_r provides me this: `Array ( [2015-02-03] => 1 [2015-05-03] => 14 )`.

But i want to restrict the query only for last 30 days in `$queryTest` variable. How i can restrict the query only to show last 30 days records? Please have a look at the sql fiddle for the table structure. [table struture](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/322397/3)

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I know. But just for demonstration purpose i mentioned this here. Thanks

Comment: I was away a bit. I am reading the replies and surely accept the most appropriate answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $dt=strtotime("-30 days")
   $dt=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$dt);
   $queryTest = 'SELECT date, count(*),count(distinct ip) FROM `visitors`  where section=\''.$page.'\' AND date>=\'' . $dt . '\' group by date order by date';
```

Comment: Hi, i see it pulls all records. I want to restrict the query only for last 30 days. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yeah now it works and returns only last 30 days records. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Do a `DATE_SUB()` with `BETWEEN` in the filter statements -

```
SELECT date, count(*),count(distinct ip) FROM `visitors`  where section=\''.$page.'\' AND date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW() group by date order by date
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But when i run this query and its prints `Array ( [2015-02-03] => 1 )`. So its pulling Month February record. I meant to pull only **last** 30 days record. For example 6 May to 6 April(as today is 6 May here and it should pull last 30 days result to 6 April. I appreciate your help

Comment: Okay i am running your updated query. Will come back shortly.

Comment: Hi, I get an empty array now when i print_r to see the records in the loop. I do have records for last 30 days. Why its returning empty array?

Comment: Swtich the dates around, I may have gone the wrong direction. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to calculate ‛30 DAY‛ interval from ‛NOW‛

```
SELECT date, count(*),count(distinct ip) 
FROM `visitors` where date >= DATE(NOW() - 
INTERVAL 30 DAY)  AND date <= NOW() group by date order by 
date;
```

You can also use BETWEEN clause on you WHERE condition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The query should return only last 30 days records. I see its getting February records. I want to restrict the query for only last 30 days.